# Why is the loop in this function run twice if called as a function, but not if called outside?

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

In Python, I have a SQL query that returns something like this:

```
[(datetime.time(1, 43), datetime.date(2022, 9, 22), 'Pontefract', 'Yorkshire Wonder Horse Apprentice Handicap', '4', Decimal('0.75'), Decimal('0.10'), 5, 'Sixcor', '', Decimal('13.00'), 'Harry Russell', 'Linda Perratt', '61.23', 4, '', Decimal('62.00'), Decimal('61.00'), Decimal('0.00'), 'Raced wide, held up in rear, ridden and headway over 1f out, disputing second inside final 110yds, kept on                            (op 14/1)', 10, 1775578, 
datetime.date(2022, 9, 22), datetime.time(1, 43), 'Pontefract', 'Yorkshire Wonder Horse Apprentice Handicap', 'Flat', Decimal('1008.60'), '', '65', ' 3yo+', 11, 3, 99, Decimal('63.00'), 'Good', 0, 0, Decimal('3833.00'), Decimal('1799.00'), Decimal('899.00'), Decimal('449.00'), Decimal('333.00'), Decimal('333.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), '6', 182125)]
```

I have designed this function to run over this code. For _ in SQL should run this once, as there is only 1 entry in this list - right? I confirmed it by len(), so it is only one entry - and the function is not called twice, I also checked that.

```
def crosslistappender(sql, fff, class1, crosspositionlist, crossdwinnerlist, crossnextlist, crossgrouplist, crosshigherwinlist, crosshigherplacelist, crossclassratinglist):
    for _ in sql:
        try:
            crosshorsename = sql[fff][8]
            crossposition = sql[fff][4]
            crossdwinner = sql[fff][5]
            crossnext = sql[fff][6]
            crossclass = sql[fff][46]
            crossgroup = sql[fff][28]
            crossclassrating = sql[fff][29]
            # add die Sachen zu einer Liste
            crosspositionlist.append(crossposition)
            crossdwinnerlist.append(crossdwinner)
            crossnextlist.append(crossnext)
            crossgrouplist.append(crossgroup)
            crossclassratinglist.append(crossclassrating)
            if crossposition == '1' and int(crossclass) < int(class1):
                crosshigherwinlist.append(crossposition)
            if crossposition == '2' or crossposition == '3' and int(crossclass) < int(class1):
                crosshigherplacelist.append(crossposition)

            fff += 1
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    return(crosspositionlist,crossdwinnerlist,crossnextlist, crossgrouplist, crosshigherwinlist, crosshigherplacelist)
```

Now the problem is - this loop runs twice, not once.

If I copy the code and use it not as a function, it does indeed run only once, as intended.

Why is it running twice inside the function?

**+++ EDIT +++**

So, I changed the call of the function to this:

```
print(horse1, datenew, datetoday, crshorsename)
print('calling the function')
crosspositionlist = crosslistappender(crossformsql2R, 0, class1, crosspositionlist, crossdwinnerlist, crossnextlist, crossgrouplist, crosshigherwinlist, crosshigherplacelist, crossclassratinglist)[0]
print('function finished')
```

And added some print statements to the function:

```
def crosslistappender(sql, ggg, class1, list, crossdwinnerlist, crossnextlist, crossgrouplist, crosshigherwinlist, crosshigherplacelist, crossclassratinglist):
    print('started function')
    print('len', (len(sql)))
    fff = 0
    for _ in sql:
        print('started loop, run Nr', fff)
        try:
            crosshorsename = sql[fff][8]
            crossposition = sql[fff][4]
            crossdwinner = sql[fff][5]
            crossnext = sql[fff][6]
            crossclass = sql[fff][46]
            crossgroup = sql[fff][28]
            crossclassrating = sql[fff][29]
            # add die Sachen zu einer Liste
            list.append(crossposition)
            print(crossposition, 'appended')
            crossdwinnerlist.append(crossdwinner)
            crossnextlist.append(crossnext)
            crossgrouplist.append(crossgroup)
            crossclassratinglist.append(crossclassrating)
            if crossposition == '1' and int(crossclass) < int(class1):
                crosshigherwinlist.append(crossposition)
            if crossposition == '2' or crossposition == '3' and int(crossclass) < int(class1):
                crosshigherplacelist.append(crossposition)
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        fff += 1
        print('Looped ', fff, 'times')
    
    return(list,crossdwinnerlist,crossnextlist, crossgrouplist, crosshigherwinlist, crosshigherplacelist)
```

**Result:**

```
Nodsasgoodasawink 2022-09-16 2022-09-30 Sixcor
calling the function
started function
len 1
started loop, run Nr 0
4 appended
Looped  1 times
function finished
started function
len 1
started loop, run Nr 0
4 appended
Looped  1 times`
```

**So - the function starts two times - but is not called twice as the statement: print('calling the function') is only printed once!?**

Comment: Why do you believe that the loop is running twice?

Comment: Because I get the result twice. In the above mentioned example, if I use this: crosspositionlist = crosslistappender(crossformsql2R, 0, class1, crosspositionlist, crossdwinnerlist, crossnextlist, crossgrouplist, crosshigherwinlist, crosshigherplacelist, crossclassratinglist)[0] - I get the '5' for the position twice in the list

Comment: Oh - and because I added a simple "print" statement in the loop, and it gets printed twice ;) So, yeah, the loop runs twice

Comment: Add the code that calls this function, and a print at the start of the function for `len(sql)`.

Comment: Did so! So the function runs twice, not just the loop - why is it invoked twice with one calling statement? @ticster